# List of essential tools to maintain an Ortler Mainau bicycle

Tags: maintenance, tools

We have three [Ortler Mainau](https://www.bikester.co.uk/ortler-mainau-trekking-bike-black-551193.html) bicycles in our family that I would like to maintain. We don't have a garage but only a smallish cellar, and I would like to work there (e.g. I cannot use toxic things there).

The maintenance tasks I would like to do in short term:
  - Adjust the breaks/gear/seat post/etc. as it is necessary.
  - Regularly clean the chains
  - Fix a flat tire

The tasks I would like to do medium term (if I need):
  - Fix a slightly warped and twisted wheel
  - Fix the lightting
  - Rewire the breaks/gears if it is necessery

I have no tools at all, so my question is that what tools I have to buy in order to be able to maintain those bikes in short term?

I live in Switzerland close to the Alps so the weather is quite wet (e.g. I assume that I need different oil for wet weather than for dry weather).

Thank you in advance!

*(Updated according to the admin requirements)*

Comment: Your question as phrased is too broad -- similar to this question which was closed for that reason: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/what-are-the-absolute-essentials-a-cyclist-should-own

Comment: You may want to look at these questions: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/38398/minimalist-setup-for-a-travelling-bike-mechanic   and    https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31876/what-is-the-necessary-equipment-on-longer-bike-rides   and   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/338/riding-repair-kit?rq=1

Comment: Hi @RoboKaren, thank you for the comment! I am not sure if the question is broad (I don't think it is), but I agree with you on that the answer can be long. Thank you also for the links. Although there are similarities between the questions, I am not looking for tools that I can carry with myself all the time. I think the question is quite realistic: you don't have any tools, you have a bike that you want to maintain, you go to the shop, what should you buy in that case. If you are experienced, you have some ideas. I am not, so I am looking for those ideas. :) + Again: the links were good. :)

Comment: Broad in stackexchange terms can include things that are too vague or too long to be canonically answered. For example, you don't set any limits as to budget or weight. So I might think you absolutely need headset bearing facers in your toolkit, regardless of the cost and that a home mechanic would most likely never use them (but if you did need them, you would). One could easily come up with a $10,000 list of must-have items -- just as another could come up with the < $150 list. Basically, you as the OP have to select one answer as "best" - what is your criteria?

Comment: I'm likely to vote to close as too broad, as you say it depends on what you include in the definition of 'maintenance'. The answer could be: a fully equipped bike repair shop! However, my advice is a set of basic general tools: metric hex wrenches, torx wrenches, metric open/ring wrenches, set of medium pliers, set small-medium flat/Philips screwdrivers. Buy bicycle specific tools as needed when you start to replace major components. You'll need a kit to take with you on rides including tire levers and a good bike multitool; also bike cleaning kit including degreaser and chain lube.

Comment: Is this a real or hypothetical question? "List should also include things like: a bottle of WD40, bicycle assembly stand because otherwise it is quite difficult to remove the read (sic) wheel" points in the direction that you already have an answer in mind and want to debate (WD40 is very limited use with bikes and it's entirely possible to remove rear wheel or build an entire bike from components without work stand)

Comment: You say "clean the chain" and "rewire the gears" but replacing the chain and cassette, even the chainrings /crankset is much more likely than changing cables now they're all stainless (and require more tools)

Comment: @ojs Yes, it's a real question. I am in a situation described above. I have an opened tab in my browser to buy the things I will need, but I do not even know what things I should buy. For example: I realized that maybe a tool box would be the most complete solution. But in some toolboxes there are chain wear gauge, in some there are not. But I know that it is important to have one. In some there are chain opener, in some there are not. My problem is that I don't know what to buy, because it seems that I can easily left something important out.

Comment: If you know that it's important to have a chain gauge, the first step is to forget everything you know.

Comment: Start with one of those 20-25 piece toolkits in a blown-plasic case, and add tools as you find need for them.  They're good enough, and I'm still using about half of what came in mine.  I've replaced the chain tool, added extra spanners and cone spanners, and added tools that weren't in the kit like a chain joiner pliers and cable cutter.      Buy decent tools as you need them, when you need them.

Answer (score 4):

Lennard Zinn has written books on maintaining road and mountain bikes (a trekking bike probably falls under the "road bike" category in terms of maintenance). He lists four levels of tool kits based on how ambitious you want to get with servicing your bike. I think this is a reasonable approach, especially since we don't know how ambitious you want to get servicing your bikes in particular.

Also, to some extent, a tool's necessity will be determined by what kind of bike you have, for instance, my road bike has no torx bolts; with a carbon bike, a torque wrench is probably more important. So any advice also needs to be tempered by the bike you're servicing.

Comment: Very good point, thank you for the comment and the link. I am going to buy one of these books. Currently I am really curious, and would like to keep the bikes in a healthy state. In the last three months I have not cleaned the chains, but used the bike for daily commuting. I have a lot of strange, rusty mud on it that is quite difficult to clean up. I do not even know what liquid I should buy to clean it properly. I bought some kind of oil, but it does not seem to help.

Answer (score -2):

Multitool is enough. Other to do in bicycle workshop.
Also patch comlect. Pump. and teargas ballon for stupid dogs )))

[image]

Comment: Where in the world can you buy a teargas balloon for stupid dogs? That sounds like a great invention.

Comment: Guessing from Sergio's profile: Russia and some other former Soviet Union countries.